# ¿Cómo escribir en una posición exacta de un archivo?

Tags: c++

Quisiera saber que técnica o si hay alguna biblioteca que me ayude a escribir en una posición exacta de un archivo txt. Lo que intente hacer fue implementar un contador que me indicara en que línea esta el cursor en el archivo y entonces escribir en esa línea, pero lo que intento escribir se va al final. En el ejemplo debería de situarse en la posición del numero 4 en el archivo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream lectura;
  ofstream archivo;
  lectura.open("prueba.txt", ios::in);
  archivo.open("prueba.txt", ios::out);
  string linea;

  string frase = "Hola Mundo";
  int cont =0;
  int espacio = 4;

  if(archivo.is_open() && lectura.is_open()){
    for(int i =0; i <=10; i++){
        archivo<< i <<endl;
    }
    while (!lectura.eof()) {
        getline(lectura, linea);
        if(espacio == cont){
            archivo << frase <<endl;
        }
        cont++;
        cout << linea << endl;
    }


}else{
    cout<<"Error"<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> pero lo que intento escribir se va al final

Los archivos no se pueden gestionar así. No debes abrir un mismo archivo dos veces y menos si mezclas el modo lectura con el modo escritura. Estos dos modos pueden bloquearse entre sí, de tal forma que tu programa puede dar error o quedarse pillado.

Para actualizar (añadir o borrar información) un archivo al vuelo lo que tienes que hacer es generar un archivo temporal y, posteriormente, reemplazar tu archivo original por el temporal:

```
std::ifstream in("prueba.txt", ios::in);
std::ofstream out("temp.txt", ios::out);

string frase = "Hola Mundo";
int cont =0;
int espacio = 4;

if(in.is_open() && out.is_open()){
    while (!in.eof()) {
        string linea;
        getline(in, linea);
        if(espacio == cont){
            out << frase <<endl;
        }
        cont++;
        out << linea << endl;
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
    
    rename("temp.txt", "prueba.txt");
    
}else{
    std::cout<<"Error"<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: muchas gracias, con esto me aclaraste muchas cosas :D

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Cómo escribir en una posición exacta de un archivo?

No se puede, los archivos no funcionan así.

---

C++ no tiene control sobre cómo se guarda un archivo, eso es responsabilidad del sistema operativo, que puede decidir guardarlo de manera secuencial o [fragmentado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desfragmentaci%C3%B3n) en diferentes pedazos guardados en diferentes posiciones del sistema de almacenamiento.

Dado que desde el lenguaje no es posible controlar cómo se guardan los archivos, no puedes elegir escribir el archivo a la carta. Lo que sí puedes hacer es copiar todo el archivo a memoria, modificar la memoria y volcar la memoria a archivo.